# Pass PHP variable to MySQL trigger #nette

Tags: mysql, nette

I have trigger created in my database. I need to pass PHP variable to that trigger.

I tried executing something like this in PhpMyAdmin:

```
SET @myVariable = 123;
INSERT INTO table (foo) VALUES (bar);
```

Trigger successfully take @myVariable - So I tried it in Nette project, but I was not successfull.

First, Prepared Statement can execute only one command, so I am not able to call SET and INSERT together.

Then I found information that variable should be valid for whole connection, so I tried call `$database->query('SET @myVariable = 123');` after connecting to database. Then I tried INSERT. But again, I was not successfull.

Anybody have any idea how to pass PHP variable to trigger?

Comment: `$database->query('SET @myVariable = 123');` looks like the Nette frameworks query function i would analyse that query function to see if there are query anny execution restrictings like only executing a query when the string starts with SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE for example.... Normally this should work fine in native PHP database query function calls like `mysqli_query("SET @myVariable = 123");` or as preparared statement `mysqli_prepare("SET @myVariable = 123")`

Comment: I think the variable was set successfully, but the trigger can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the problem was when I used variables with string. When I assigned integer value to variable, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For set variable is suitable QUERY command. Never concatenate strings, always add the parameters with the question mark (SQL injection vulnerability)

```
$database->query('SET @myVariable = ?', 123);
$database->query('INSERT INTO table ?', ['foo' => bar]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a variable explicitly to a particular value, use a SET statement.

**Syn:**

> SET @variable = value

**Ex:**

```
$db->query('SET @myVariable=?', '123' ); OR use mysql as mention above.
```

A set variable’s value persists until you assign it another value or until the end of your session.

So you can get your variable in Trigger,using  select statement.

**Syn:**

> SELECT @variable;

**Ex:**

In Trigger

```
IF (condition) THEN
  SET myVariable_t = (SELECT @myVariable);
   INSERT INTO table
     SET column_name = myVariable_t,          
END IF;
```

Comment: The problem was with string variables. When I assigned number value, everything is OK.

Comment: Are you using PDO? you can use parameter as an array and pass the value. It will work.
I have tested with string like ip address, url etc, its works properly.